# Partial Method Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ class with a template method in Logger.hpp and I want to add specializationis to it to support other classes, such as an specialization in Player.hpp. I suppose what I'm going to achieve is called "partial method specialization", please correct me if I'm wrong.

I tried the following (simplified) code:

**Logger.hpp**

```
class Logger {
  public:
  template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes> void log(T message, ArgTypes... args) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    // do more with args...
  }
};
```

**Player.hpp**

```
#include "Logger.hpp"

class Player {
  public:
  Player(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}
  std::string getName() const { return name; }

  private:
  std::string name;
};

// add support for logger->log(myPlayer, 19, 11)
// (19 and 11 are arbitrary arguments and can be of any number and types)

// unfortunately this line does not compile
// (declaration is incompatible with function template "void Logger::log(T message, ArgTypes ...args)")
template<typename... ArgTypes> void Logger::log<Player>(Player message, ArgTypes... args) {
  std::cout << "Player(name=" << message.getName() << ")" << std::endl;
  // do more with args...
}
```

How should I add the functionality to my Logger class to allow me to log my Player class (and other classes later)?

I do NOT want to add the specialication in Logger.hpp. It should be possible to handle Logger.hpp like a library and anyone is free to add support for their types in *their* code.

Also note that I pass a variadic argument (typename... ArgTypes) following the typed first argument.

Also note that overloading the << operator on the C++ output class is also NOT an option since the cout lines will be replaced by a different code later.

Comment: The only way to do something like that (as best as I could understand this question) is to overload the `<<` operator, and since that's not an option for you, I see no other solution. C++ simply does not work the way you want C++ to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround that will work in my specific case and it might also be the solution for others, having this kind of issue.

Instead of the first log parameter T being a template parameter, I choose the specific type std::string. As for other classes, I simply add a std::string conversion operator, which will produce any string I want.

This works fine for me since I'm dealing with strings in the end and I want to do the same with the args every time. The new code looks like this:

**Logger.hpp**

```
class Logger {
  public:
  template<typename... ArgTypes> void log(std::string message, ArgTypes... args) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    // do more with args...
  }
};
```

**Player.hpp**

```
#include "Logger.hpp"

class Player {
  public:
  Player(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}
  std::string getName() const { return name; }
  operator std::string() const {
    return std::string("Player(name=") + name + ")";
  }

  private:
  std::string name;
};
```

---

If I don't want to use the string conversion or if I want to pass some of the args to my function, another solution would be using base and sub class. Something like this could work (not tested):

**Logger.hpp**

```
class Loggable {
  public:
  virtual void logMe() = 0;
};

class Logger {
  public:
  template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes> void log(T message, ArgTypes... args) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    // do more with args...
  }

  template<typename... ArgTypes> void log(Loggable *loggable, ArgTypes... args) {
    loggable->logMe();
  }
};
```

**Player.hpp**

```
#include "Logger.hpp"

class Player : public Loggable {
  public:
  Player(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}
  std::string getName() const { return name; }
  void logMe() override {
    std::cout << "Player(name=" << message.getName() << ")" << std::endl;
  }

  private:
  std::string name;
};
```